# CSS margin only after first div in each row?

Tags: html, css

I want to display some div's in a wrap. The div have same class name and have fixed width. I want to set some margin-right to the first divs in the row, but not to the last div in the row, but the problem is that I **can't change the html**.
if its not possible with the CSS, can it be done with jQuery?
**Edit**: Sorry, forgot to mention, there are always 2 divs in a row.

```
<div class="list">

<div class="box">Box 1</div> 
<div class="box">Box 2</div> <!-- should be margin-right:0 --> 
<div class="box">Box 3</div> 
<div class="box">Box 4</div> <!-- should be margin-right:0 --> 

</div>
```

Comment: Is the amount of `box`-divs per row variable?

Comment: One thing to note here is that the answers provided below will not be truely cross browser nor cross browser version. The most reliable and safe method to do this is in server-side language.

Comment: No, its always 2. Sorry, forgot to mention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

now used to this

first option

```
.box:nth-of-type(2n){
margin-right:0;
}
```

---

second option

```
.box:nth-child(even){
margin-right:0;
}
```

more info http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: This is good just for new browsers who support nth-of-type or even. IE8+

Comment: @FlorescuAdrian just add a polyfill for the case you need to support IE<=8: http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: On resizing the `2n` won't be at the same place anymore?

Answer (score 2):

You can use css3 `last-child` property for this. write like this:

```
.box:last-child{
 margin-right:0;
}
```

But it's not it's IE8 & below

As per your requirement you can use + selector for this. Write like this:

```
.box + .box{
 margin-left:10px;
}
```

& it's work till IE7

Answer (score 2):

```
div:not(:last-child) { margin-right: 10px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need this http://csswizardry.com/2011/08/building-better-grid-systems/